# Cursor position inside WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, position

I try to set the cursor in specific location inside form, this is ok when form is maximized but when size of the form is changed cursor position is outside of the form

Sorry for my English.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int xp = 585;
    int yp = 330;
    Cursor.Position = PointToClient(new Point(xp, yp));
    Point mousep = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
    tbX1.Text = mousep.X.ToString();
    tbY1.Text = mousep.Y.ToString();
}
```

Comment: so, determine your cursor position according the current size of your form instead of using fixed values?

Comment: Most users do not enjoy having the mouse icon moved for them

Comment: I have webbrowser control inside the form and I want to read tooltip programaticaly ... this work but I cant set the specific cursor position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the variables xp and yp are the offset inside the window...

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(Location.X + xp, Location.Y + yp);
```